Issue typing custom hook parameter on vi.spyOn
I'm using Vite for a React + TypeScript project.
I'm currently trying to test some parts of the app using Vitest and I'm facing this problem when I'm tyring to mock data that I receive from a custom hook that returns loading, error and fetched data.

When I'm using vi.spyOn TypeScript is complaning that the second value passed as string ('usePodcasterData') which is the name of the method is a string and it should be never type:
Argument of type '() =\> \[RootObject | undefined, boolean, boolean\]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)

    const usePodcasterDataSpy = vi.mock(usePodcasterData, 'usePodcasterData');
    
    usePodcasterDataSpy.mockReturnValue({
        podcastData: mockPodcastData,
        isLoading: false,
        hasError: false
    });

I know that all types used in the app working well and I dont have any other issue related with typing.
Already tried with vi.mock and I have another problem related with types.
In case you want to take a look: music-app
eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any \*/
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from "vitest";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import PodcastList from "../components/PodcastList";
import usePodcasterData from "../hooks/usePodcasterData";
import { RootObject } from "../types"; // Asegúrate de importar los tipos correctamente

const mockPodcastData: RootObject = {"here goes mocked data"};

describe("PodcastList", () =\> {
// Mock the return value of usePodcasterData
const usePodcasterDataSpy = vi.mock(usePodcasterData, 'usePodcasterData');

    usePodcasterDataSpy.mockReturnValue({
        podcastData: mockPodcastData,
        isLoading: false,
        hasError: false
    });
    
    it("renders the podcasts correctly", () => {
        render(<PodcastList />);
    
        expect(screen.getByText(/Podcast One/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByText(/Artist One/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByText(/Podcast Two/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByText(/Artist Two/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

});


The second argument to vi.mock should be a factory function to create the test double, why pass a string?! Also the first argument should be a string. Read the docs: https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mock, https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#modules

Im usign the documentation to mock usePodcastData like this:
beforeAll(() => {
vi.mock('../hooks/usePodcasterData', async (importOriginal) => {
const originalModule = await importOriginal<typeof import('../hooks/usePodcasterData')>();
return {
...originalModule,
default: vi.fn(() => [mockPodcastData, false, false]),
};
});
}); but still facing issues
